# Display streaming video in desktop app

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, video-streaming, directshow

I have a Windows native desktop app (C++/Delphi), and I'm successfully using Directshow to display live video in it from a 'local' video capture device.

The next thing I want to do is display video from a 'remote' capture device, streamed over the LAN.

To stream the video, I guess I can use something like [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/encoderpro_overview.aspx) or [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), but I'm not sure what's the easiest way to receive/decode the streamed video. Inserting an ActiveX VLC or Flash player might be one option (although the licensing may be an issue then), but I was wondering if there's any way to achieve this with Directshow...

Application needs to run on XP, and the video decoding should ideally be royalty free.

Suggestions, please!

Answer (score 2):

Using Directshow for receiving and displaying your video can work, but the simplicity, "openness" and performances will depend on the video format and streaming method you'll be using.

A lot of open/free source filters exist for RTSP (e.g. based on [live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/)), but you may also find that creating your own source filter is a better fit.

The best solution won't be the same for H264 diffusion through RTP/RTSP and for MJPEG diffusion through simple UDP.